# loop throught classes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make progress bars using JS.

I am trying to loop through my classes to get the value of an attribute and thus increase the width of my progress bars.

```
function prog(){
    var width = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    var attr = elem.getAttribute("data-progress");

    function frame(){
        if(width >= attr){
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {    
            width++;

            for(i= 0; i < elem.length; i++){
                elem[i].style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, **How do i access attr inside a loop in JS?**

Comment: Is value of `attr` constant here - `let attr = el.getAttribute("data-progress");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for ... of` loop to go through all your elements :

```js
function prog() {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
  let width = 1;

  for (let el of elem) { //HERE
    let attr = el.getAttribute("data-progress");

    let id = setInterval(_ => {
      if (width >= attr) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
          elem[i].style.width = width + '%';
        }
      }
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: when i fire this code i got error from  let id = setInterval(frame, 10); said frame is undefined and the code is not working where im going to put the frame function now ?

Comment: It does not make sense setting `setInterval` inside a for loop

Comment: @dhaker It does if he intends to do something for every element of his.